# Specifying Script language for Tesseract

Tags: tesseract

Tesseract 4.0.0 added Script files to the language files, which are in the `tessdata/script` directory.  This page, https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#LANGUAGES, implies that the -l option accepts the name of a language or script.  I assumed it would look in `tessdata` first and if not found, would look in `tessdata/script`.  But it seems you have to enter the path.  Is this the expected behavior?

For example:

```
c:\Users\>tesseract -l Latin c:\TestFiles\english-sentence.jpg stdout
Error opening data file c:\Program Files\tesseract-OCR/tessdata/Latin.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'Latin'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.

c:\Users\>tesseract -l script/Latin c:\TestFiles\english-sentence.jpg stdout
my house has a tree in the front and a car in the
back
```

The `tesseract --list-langs` command output looks like this

```
por
pus
que
ron
rus
san
script/Arabic
script/Armenian
script/Bengali
script/Canadian_Aboriginal
```

So it clearly knows about the script directory